# Angular 2 Observables implementation

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to wrap my logic using the reactive programming method.

I have two dependent data sets which may or may not be in localstorage. However i need to compute one first and then the second.

So something like this:

```
let storageCategories = this.ls.retrieve('categories');
if ( storageCategories ) {
    // Found in localStorage
    this.allCategories = storageCategories;
} else {
    // Send an HTTP API request and fetch categories
    // After request is successful lookup for 'result' in localstorage
    // If result not in localstorage send an HTTP API request
}


// RESULT LOGIC
let storageResult = this.ls.retrieve('result');
if ( storageResult ) {
    // Found in localStorage
    return new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.processResultData(storageResult));
} else {
    // Send an HTTP API request and fetch result
    // If request is successful save in localstorage and return
}
```

Now the basic problem is i don't want to write the result logic in two places: (1) The `else` of the first `if` and (2) After categories `if`

Is there a way to make the result logic just in one place (other than writing it in a new function)?

Comment: In the second else for `storageResult` are you making a http request to the same endpoint as else of `storageCategories`?

Comment: No, storageResults HTTP request is for another API call. So to clarify: I need to first check categories. If they are available in localstorage, those values will be used. If not then a request to API for categories will be sent. In both cases i have to then check the `results` value in localstorage. If its present then we use it otherwise we need to send an API request to gather result using another API call. Because these calls are async so they make a nested callback mess which i am trying to avoid and want to write code using RxJS method. I hope it clarifies the question little more.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mpzCnH0KuOWI49CYZGNF) from your explanation. See if it meets your standards and solves your problem. Here is the summary:

```
private getCategories(): Observable<any>{
if(this.categoriesInLs){
  return Observable.of("categories data");
} else {
  return this.searchService.getCategories();
}
}

private getResults(): Observable<any>{
  if(this.resultsInLs){
    return Observable.of("results data");
  } else {
    return this.searchService.getResults();
  }
}

get(){
  this.getCategories()
  .flatMap(categories => this.getResults())
  .subscribe(r => console.log(r));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim! - i will test it out and let you know :) I was not aware of `Observable.of` method. So basically you have broken down the dependency and then rejoined them in a separate method (`get()`). Nice approach :)

Comment: Could have done in one routine too but that would be ugly